# Ember.js change tracked variable in child component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to ember.js and wanna know what's the best way to alter `@tracked` variable in child component.

Assume this structure:

```
Parent
  --- Component1
```

- Parent controller

  ```
  @tracked
  number = 1
  ```
- Parent.hbs

  ```
  <Component1 @number={{this.number}} />
  {{this.number}}
  ```
- Component1.hbs

  ```
  <button {{on "click" this.addNumber}}> Add </button>
  ```
- Component1.js

  ```
  @tracked
  number = this.args.number

  @action
  addNumber(){
      this.number += 1;
      console.log(this.number)
  }
  ```

The number did addon in the `Component1` and print the number every time I clicked  the Add button, however, it didn't reflect to `Parent` level.

Comment: An alternative to that approach is to pass down an instance of a class that has a tracked property on it. That will allow it to be updated wherever it is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to Ember!

It looks like you're wanting some form of two-way binding -- which doesn't exist in Ember.

In order to update data on a parent "something", you'll need to define a function to update that data.

For example:

```js
// parent.js
export default class Parent extends Component {
  @tracked number;

  updateNumber = (nextValue) => this.number = nextValue;
}
```

```
{{! parent.hbs }}
<Component1 
  @number={{this.number}} 
  @updateNumber={{this.updateNumber}} 
/>
```

And then in Component1:

```js
// component1.js
export default class Component1 extends Component {

  addNumber = () => {
    let { updateNumber, number } = this.args;
    
    updateNumber(number + 1);
  }
}
```

```
{{! component1.hbs }}
<button {{on "click" this.addNumber}}> Add </button>
```

Note that only the "source of truth" of the data needs to be declared as tracked. Any other data involving `number` does not need to be tracked. Data using `number` can be "derived" with getters.
For example:

```js
// in component1.js
get doubled() {
  return this.args.number * 2;
}
```

No need for decorators or anything -- this vanilla - no-need-to-compile JS.

A note on something I noticed in your example:

```js
// component1.js
class Component1 extends Component {
  @tracked
  number = this.args.number

  // ...
}
```

property assignment in the body of a class only happens once, during instantiation. So, if `this.args.number` happened to be `2` at the time of instantiation, the above would be equivelant of:

```js
// component1.js
class Component1 extends Component {
  @tracked
  number = 2

  // ...
}
```

which effectively *detaches* the reactivity.
It is a handy trick though if you *want to* manage state locally in the component.

Docs on component state can be found here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/component-state-and-actions/

And an [interactive demo / repl here](https://limber.glimdown.com/?t=%23%20Limber%20Editor%0A%0A%23%23%20With%20JavaScript%0A%0Acode%20fence%20tags%20can%20be%20used%20to%20directly%20render%20components%2C%0Aas%20well%20as%20render%20the%20code%20snippet%20the%20live%20code%20comes%20from.%0A%0AOptions%3A%0A%0A%20-%20%60live%60%20-%20_renders%20in%20place_%0A%20-%20%60live%20preview%60%20_renders%20in%20place%2C%20placing%20the%20source%20after%20the%20live%20render_%0A%20-%20%60live%20preview%20below%60%20_renders%20in%20place%2C%20placing%20the%20live%20render%20below%20the%20source_%0A%0A%60%60%60gjs%20live%20preview%0Aimport%20Component%20from%20%27%40glimmer%2Fcomponent%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20tracked%20%7D%20from%20%27%40glimmer%2Ftracking%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20on%20%7D%20from%20%27%40ember%2Fmodifier%27%3B%0A%0Aclass%20Component1%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20addNumber%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20%7B%20updateNumber%2C%20number%20%7D%20%3D%20this.args%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20updateNumber(number%20%2B%201)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%3Ctemplate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%40number%7D%7D%3Cbr%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20%7B%7Bon%20%27click%27%20this.addNumber%7D%7D%3E%20%2B1%20%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Parent%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20%40tracked%20number%20%3D%200%3B%0A%0A%20%20updateNumber%20%3D%20(nextNumber)%20%3D%3E%20this.number%20%3D%20nextNumber%3B%0A%0A%20%20%3Ctemplate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CComponent1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40number%3D%7B%7Bthis.number%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40updateNumber%3D%7B%7Bthis.updateNumber%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftemplate%3E%0A%7D%0A%60%60%60%0A) (using the next-gen syntax (polyfilled via [ember-template-imports](https://github.com/ember-template-imports/ember-template-imports/)))